# Normal transformation in cube mapping

Tags: opengl

I'm currently learning about cube mapping, I found this tutorial: http://www.keithlantz.net/2011/10/lighting-and-environment-mapping-with-glsl/ He transform normal vector by multiplies with inverse of transposed `Model` matrix. I wonder why don't he multiplies by inverse of transposed `ModelView` matrix but `Model` matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cube map is defined in word space, it seems that the author wants to have texture coords in word space as well.

note that one normal is transformed to view space - for lighting, and the second is used only to lookup in cubemap.

two links for reference:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Unity/Reflecting_Surfaces
- http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing_p04.php#part_4

Comment: so, what different bettwen `fragNormal = ((inverse(transpose(ModelMatrix)) * vec4(gl_Normal, 0.0)).xyz` and `fragNormal = ((inverse(transpose(ModelViewMatrix)) * vec4(gl_Normal, 0.0)).xyz`? And what does each one affects to texture coord?

Comment: one normal is used for lighting and it is transformed by modelview to view space, the second one is used only for cube map, and it is in world space. Inverse(transpose(mat)) is used to properly transform normal vector. http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/glsl/index.php/index.php?normalmatrix

Comment: I've just added two more links as a reference. Great that I could help :)